# Setting Smoke volumes to indirect only

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, viewlayers

I have a scene where I have a smoke simulation surrounding an object. I would like to render the scene in layers so I can composite the final shot in After effects.

I can put the smoke and object in separate view layers, however, they don't effect each others lighting or shadows.

So I put the smoke in the same view layer as the object, and set its visibility to indirect only. The smoke doesn't show up in the render, but also doesn't affect the lighting of the object or cast any shadows.

How do I get two renders, one with the smoke, and another with the object, but with the smoke still effecting the lighting/shadows of the object.

Combined Render
[image]

Composited Render (creature + smoke sim)
[image]